# Why to use void(unused) (and similar) instead of no-name parameter to silence unused-variables warnings in C++ function?

Tags: c++, function

So I know two ways to mark variable as unused in C++:

**First**( in the function's body )

```
void func1(int i, int unused) {
  (void)unused; //marking 'unused' here

  i++;
}
```

and similars

**Second** (in the function's arguments list)

```
void func2(int i, int /* marking 'unused' here */ ) {
  i++;
}
```

In my opinion, second one is much better, because it:

1. Informs about unused variable on function declaration (no need to
   see implementation)
2. Makes it impossible to actually use this variable
3. Makes code clearer (that's subjective tho)

Also, assembly code generated for this two functions is equal (tested with gcc 4.9.2) so it's not about performance trade-offs either.

In view of this, my question is:  why is it so common to use first one?

Comment: Function signatures are contracts.  You intentionally broke the contract, that's fine, but a local change to the contract does not in anyway change the actual contract.  Obfuscating the contract is not helpful to get it done correctly some day.

Comment: first one makes sense when many developers are working on a single file..say you need to use it for some feature to be added later on, maybe in the next release, but, half of the work is done by changing the api and feeding the data(variable) to it in this release..

Comment: With C++11, it is now easy to assign an attribute to a potentially unused variable.  For example: `void foo(int i, int j [[gnu::unused]])`.  That way, using `j` is optional.  This can be helpful during development/testing.

Answer (score 6):

if you are in C++ you are allowed to use Second. If you got some C legacy: the second one is actually illegal.

Code:

```
int foo(int) {
    int i=0;
    return i;
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc -c -ansi -pedantic main.c
main.c: In function 'foo':
main.c:1:1: error: parameter name omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible reason is that some tools emits warning when declaration and definition parameters doesn't match.
or when argument in *special comment* doesn't match those from declaration/definition (as *Doxygen*).